# Simple question about variables into functions

Tags: functions, variable

Im trying to write a very simple code that will solve an equation.

```
total = 800;
side1 = x;
side2 = total - 2 x;
f[x_] := side1*side2
f[x]
f'[x]
Solve[f'[x]==0]
```

But what seems to be happening is that f[x] is the equation i want it to be, but it thinks the derivative is zero, which is not the case and im not sure how im messing this up. 
Thank you for any advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
total = 800;
side1 = x;
side2 = total - 2 x;
f[x_] = side1*side2;
Solve[f'[x] == 0, x]
(* {{x -> 200}} *)
```

or

```
total = 800;
side1[x_] = x;
side2[x_] = total - 2 x;
f[x_] := side1[x]*side2[x];
Solve[f'[x] == 0, x]
(* {{x -> 200}} *)
```

Answer (score 1):

This issue dives into the difference between `Set` (`=`) and `SetDelayed` (`:=`), and a somewhat unclear issue with taking the derivatives of `Unevaluated` symbols which do not explicitly depend on the variable of differentiation.

Using `SetDelayed` results in apparently identical behavior to differentiating the unevaluated symbols directly:

```
g[x_] := side1 * side2;
{g'[x], D[Unevaluated[side1 * side2], x]}
```

> {0, 0}

Differentiating with `D` provides the correct result, however, because it evaluates `g` before taking the derivative:

```
D[g[x], x]
```

> 800 - 4 x

Using `Set` performs the evaluation beforehand, and thus works properly with the `'` notation:

```
f[x_] = side1 * side2;
f'[x]
```

> 800 - 4 x

Answer (score 0):

You should have define the Sides functions.
But for F function it's ok to be defined f[x] or without defined since they already depend on sides functions already defined.

With defining f

```
total = 800;
side1[x_] := x;
side2[x_] := total - 2 x;
f[x_] := side1[x]*side2[x];
f'[x]

Solve[f'[x] == 0, x]
(*{{x -> 200}}*)

FindRoot[f'[x] == 0, {x, 0}]
(*{x -> 200.}*)
```

OR without defining f

```
total = 800;
side1[x_] := x;
side2[x_] := total - 2 x;
f = side1[x]*side2[x];
D[f, x]

Solve[D[f, x] == 0, x]
(*{{x -> 200}}*)

FindRoot[D[f, x], {x, 0}]
(*{x -> 200.}*)
```